# Oracle 8i SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle8i

In the SQL statement below I am passing ROUTER_ID and expecting to have the most recent version of RTR_HEADER record along with related RTR_SEQUENCE returned.

```
SELECT 
   RH.ROUTER_ID,
   RH.DESCRIPTION,
   RSEQ.SEQUENCE_NUMBER
FROM 
   CFG.RTR_SEQUENCE RSEQ
INNER JOIN CFG.RTR_HEADER RH
  ON RSEQ.ROUTER_ID = RH.ROUTER_ID
  AND RSEQ.ROUTER_REV = RH.ROUTER_REV
WHERE 
  RH.ROUTER_REV = (SELECT MAX(RVER.ROUTER_REV) FROM CFG.RTR_HEADER RVER WHERE RVER.ROUTER_ID = RH.ROUTER_ID) 
AND RH.ROUTER_ID = 'XXXXX-XXX'
ORDER BY RH.ROUTER_ID, RSEQ.SEQUENCE_NUMBER
```

I keep getting **SQL command not properly ended** with intelligence pointing at the INNER JOIN. If I omit the INNER JOIN and its related table and fields the SQL statement runs. I do get the recent version of the RTR_HEADER record, but I need the matching RTR_HEADER as well. I looked at many of the other existing answers here on SO, taken their resolution into consideration without any results.

[image: Visual Representation of Relationship]

[image: Intelisence displaying error]

Comment: syntax looks fine.  I assume ROUTER_ID is a string not a number.

Comment: Correct. A string value.

Comment: Are you sure you are not in 8i or checking syntax for 8i. Replace inner join with comma and move the conditions after ON into the where clause.

Comment: Are you sure Oracle 9 supports the `JOIN` operator? I think support for that was added in Oracle 10 but I might be mistaken?

Comment: *ouch! its Oracle 8i. Sorry. Being that it's 8i how should the command be structured?

Comment: ANSI join syntax was introduced in Oracle 9i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   RH.ROUTER_ID,
   RH.DESCRIPTION,
   RSEQ.SEQUENCE_NUMBER
FROM 
   CFG.RTR_SEQUENCE RSEQ,CFG.RTR_HEADER RH
WHERE RSEQ.ROUTER_ID = RH.ROUTER_ID
  AND RSEQ.ROUTER_REV = RH.ROUTER_REV
  AND RH.ROUTER_REV = (SELECT MAX(RVER.ROUTER_REV) FROM CFG.RTR_HEADER RVER WHERE RVER.ROUTER_ID = RH.ROUTER_ID) 
AND RH.ROUTER_ID = 'XXXXX-XXX'
ORDER BY RH.ROUTER_ID, RSEQ.SEQUENCE_NUMBER
```

Comment: @GeovaniMartinez For left and right old syntax see here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6585774577187